# Accent sensitive sort in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, collation, alphabetical-sort, accent-sensitive

How to sort text in PostgreSQL in Latvian alphabetic order, so any letter without accent  always comes before the letter with accent?

For example this

```sql
select * from (
    select 'bā' as name
    union select 'āa'
    union select 'ac'
    union select 'Āb'
    union select 'Ā'
) t
order by name COLLATE "lv-x-icu"
```

returns `Ā āa Āb ac bā`

but the expected result is `ac Ā āa Āb bā`

I have tried to create some custom collations but none of them returned the expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an unusual requirement. In natural language collations (including the Latuvian collation), strings are compared in different steps:

- In the first step, punctuation, case and accents are ignored.  If the strings compare differently, that determines the sorting order.  This is called a difference on the *primary level*.
- If the strings are equal on the primary level, only punctuation and case are ignored, but accents matter.  If the strings compare differently, that determines the sorting order.  This is a difference on the *secondary level*.
- If the strings are equal on the secondary level, only punctuation is ignored, but accents and case matter.  This is the *tertiary level*.
- Finally, if the strings are equal on the tertiary level, differences in punctuation (the *quaternary level*) matter.

That explains the sort order you see: since `a < aa < ab < ac <ba` on the primary level, accents are not taken into account.

If you want `ac < Ā`, you want accents to be considered different on the primary level, as if `a` and `ā` were different letters. For that, you'd have to use an ICU collation and customize it with additional rules. This is only possible from v16 on:

```
CREATE COLLATION latuvian_custom (
   PROVIDER = icu,
   LOCALE = 'lv',
   RULES = '& a < ā & A < Ā & c < č & C < Č & e < ē & E < Ē & g < ģ & G < Ģ & k < ķ & K < Ķ & l < ļ & L < Ļ & n < ņ & N < Ņ & s < š & S < Š & u < ū & U < Ū & z < ž & Z < Ž'
);

select * from (
    select 'bā' as name
    union select 'āa'
    union select 'ac'
    union select 'Āb'
    union select 'Ā'
) t
order by name COLLATE latuvian_custom;

 name 
══════
 ac
 Ā
 Āb
 āa
 bā
(5 rows)
```

The rules introduce a primary level difference (`<`) between the unaccented and the accented characters.

Comment: I salute you Laurenz. Great answer.

Comment: This works on PostgreSQL v16, thanks! Let's see if there are any solutions for older pg versions, because we are using PostgreSQL v14 and there are no plans for upgrading in near future.

Comment: I have reworked the answer to explain what is going on and remove the focus on case differences. I am pretty certain that you cannot create a collation like that in PostgreSQL versions below v16.

Answer (score 1):

A small supplement to [@Laurenz'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77288282/5298879): in order to achieve the desired result of `ac Ā āa Āb bā` specified in the question, accents need to be considered at the primary level, but case shouldn't. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NyMjRYNU):

```
CREATE COLLATION latvian_custom (PROVIDER=icu,LOCALE='lv',
   RULES='&a<Ā=ā &c<Č=č &e<Ē=ē &g<Ģ=ģ &i<Ī=ī &k<Ķ=ķ 
          &l<Ļ=ļ &n<Ņ=ņ &s<Š=š &u<Ū=ū &z<Ž=ž'
);
SELECT string_agg(sample, E'\t' ORDER BY sample COLLATE "latvian_custom") 
FROM (VALUES ('bā'),('āa'),('ac'),('Āb'),('Ā')) AS _(sample);
```

| string_agg |
| --- |
| ac Ā āa Āb bā |

At that stage, all non-accented characters are already equal to their uppercase variant, so it should be enough to anchor the [equal accented pairs](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Rules) behind either (e.g. `&A<Ā=ā` or `&a<Ā=ā`). Both case variants of each accented character need to be anchored as equal - as additions, they are treated independently, so it [wouldn't work](https://dbfiddle.uk/GEyDydQo) if you only do `&a<ā &c<č...&z<ž`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/epGplNBz)'s a comparison:

| collation_name | sorted_samples |
| --- | --- |
| **expected** | **ac Ā āa Āb bā** *(OP's example)* |
| default | ac bā Ā Āb āa |
| latUvian_custom | ac Ā Āb āa bā |
| **latvian_custom** | **ac Ā āa Āb bā** *(the only match)* |
| latvian_lower_first | Ā āa Āb ac bā |
| latvian_lower_first_custom | ac Ā Āb āa bā |
| latvian_upper_first | Ā āa Āb ac bā |
| latvian_upper_first_custom | ac Ā Āb āa bā |
| lv-LV-x-icu | Ā āa Āb ac bā |
| lv-x-icu | Ā āa Āb ac bā |
| unicode | Ā āa Āb ac bā |

Comment: Thank you for the research and detailed answer!